# Chartjs - Dataset colors are getting overloaded with angular-chartjs

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using the angularjs wrapper of the Chartjs. I am updating  the graph when the new data receive from a push event program. Also I am coloring in-between selected graph data sets.

When I go to another page and come back to the graph page again, the opacity of the color of the dataset getting increased and ultimately opacity goes away.
It seems to me that the data set colors are doesn't get cleared when I revisit the page. However this issue get solved when I refresh the page.

How can I clear the previous data set details when I revisit.

I tried the chart.clear() but didn't work

Comment: Which versions are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.7 version of chartjs

Answer (score 0):

[angular-chartjs](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) is outdated and don't really work with the newer versions of [chartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/).

Check this issue out: [#677](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/677).

The issuer gives an example on how to implement chartJS with a wrapper. You need to be aware of the fact that chartJS alone don't handle the colors anymore. You need to set them on your own.

On the other hand if you really don't want to do it on your own you could try [my wrapper implementation](https://github.com/MrWook/mw-chart) for chartJS.